# IfIndex calculation Huawei

Tags: snmp, calculation

I'm trying to interface to a Huawei device (MA5608T) via Python through SNMP.I learned that there is a correspondence between the index value and the port.

But I still don't understand how it translates

for example:
4194445056.0(index) = 0/17/7(port)

does anyone know what are the steps to do?

Comment: The formula is probably proprietary and secret (to Huawei), but Huawei will probably have a private MIB that lets you query those parameters. Google Huawei port and you will probably find it.

Comment: Search the web for 'Huawei ifIndex Mib encoding rules'. It is proprietary but it is no secret. It depends on Porttype Frame/Slot/Port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

`4194304000 + (slot * (256 * 32)) + pon * 256) + '.' + onu_id`

Answer (score 0):

This Javascript code is taken from production. The binary operations will give you a clue on how to extract the data from the packet.

```js
function convert_snmp_packet( packet ){
    
    let regex = /[^\.]*/g;
    let found = packet.match( regex );

    if( found.length < 2 ) {
        throw new Error( "wrong packet ? " + packet );
    }

    let left_part = parseInt( found[0] );
    // found[1] is just the dot
    let ont_index = parseInt( found[ 2 ] );
    let slot_num;
    let port_num;


    slot_num = ( left_part & ( 15 << 13 ) ) >> 13;
    port_num = ( left_part & ( 15 << 8 ) ) >> 8;

    let json = {
        slot_num: slot_num, 
        port_num: port_num, 
        ont_index: ont_index
    };
    return json;
}
```

test code:

```js
class packet_Test extends Test {
    test_packet(  ){
        // packet must be a String for this to work
        let p =  "4194445056.0";
        let actual = convert_snmp_packet( p );
        let expected = { slot_num: 1, port_num: 7, ont_index: 0 };
        this.assertEquals( expected, actual );
        this.done()
    }
}
```

Sorry for the necromancy. Ran into this while looking for information about SNMP over a Huawei olt.